# Add cache prefix to images source with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I'm trying to add some no-cache prefix to images:

```
var cacheId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
$(this).attr('src', src + cacheId);
```

but i have an error: `src is not defined`, what is wrong?

Comment: you haven't defined the the variable src

Comment: i need to add only some sign to src, i don't need variable

Comment: Try this http://www.dummies.com/how-to/computers-software/programming/javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable named `src` is is currently undefined.

I believe you want to do something like this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LnJJ/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("img").each(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var cacheId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
        $(this).attr('src', src + "?r=" + cacheId);
    });
});
```